# Send Mail in Dotnetnuke

Tags: asp.net, .net, content-management-system, dotnetnuke

sending function in dnn for modules works good, ex :`Contact Us` , but when new user wants to register or reset password sending mail being fail.

1. Smtp Setting in both `Site setting` and `Host setting` Works Good
2. if user email and `smtp mail account user name` is same all works
   fine, but when it is different, Email not sent because mail server
   not allow this (authenticate as `a` send mail as `b`) .

i have checked smtp mail server log for solution , i founded that dnn try to send mail from : `user account email` but authenticate from different address so mail server prevent this action. 
mail server log :

```
--> 235 2.7.0 Authentication successful
Authenticated as info@neyriz.ir
<-- MAIL FROM:<moslem7026@gmail.com>
--> 530 5.7.0 Authentication required
Connection closed
SMTP session terminated (Bytes in/out: 119/323)
```

on new Problem Found :

```
all users that want to reset their password , reset link sent to administrator from user email !!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

Dotnetneuke Mail system for smtp authentication use account that has been set in `host setting` or `portal setting` and send mail from administrator email. some mail servers prevent send mail from address that is different from ones that has been authenticated. best way is that administrator email in profile and setting be same to prevent any kind of this problem